# Configure SOLR to find documents if the plural is used in the document, and the singular in the search text?

Tags: solr

I am using solr, set up at localhost:8983
I am basically using the out of the box example.
I have entered one document with a name "Car", and another with a name "Cars".

If I visit either:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=Car
```

or

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=Cars
```

I would expect to get both documents.  At the moment, I don't.

In the fields tag of "schema.xml", the entry for "name" is:

"text_general" has the following "analyzers" (without the stemmers):

```xml
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

I tried to add a stemmer to each analyzer.  I tried:

```xml
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
```

Doing so makes it such that searching for "Cars" will find "Car", but I can never find "Cars".

Should it be possible to find "Cars"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible, just add porter filter at the end (after LowerCaseFilterFactory):

```xml
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
```

Read more:

1. [Snowball docs with example of use in analyser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballPorterFilterFactory.html)
2. [Solr LanguageAnalysis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory)
3. [The English (Porter2) stemming algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html)

If there is no special need, I would not divide analyser to index and query time. Your query time analyser looks perfectly good to use it in both cases.

Comment: Hey, that seems to work.  And now, so do the stemmers I tried yesterday.  I was restarting the solr application (running on tomcat), and it did appear to have some effect (i.e. I could never find "Cars", no matter what I did), but I guess something was being cached.  I will take your advice about the division of the analyser.  Thanks.

Comment: @Fuxi Your first link is dead and also the third

Comment: @AntonioCS I updated first link, second and thing works for me

Comment: @Fuxi Yes, the third is working for me now too :) Thanks for the quick update

Answer (score 1):

I found that changing from text_general to text_en in the shema.xml fields took care of this plurality problem

Comment: Are you referring to exemplary schema in Solr? In versions I checked it's also using stemming, PorterStemFilterFactory to be exact