# Advanced Search Java Library

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, solr, lucene

I am adding functionality of advanced search to JSF Based CMS product

Search criteria :

> If User Searches with keyword Assets then he should be able to get records containing Asset As well as Assets

I found that Lucene and Solr are the best way to do full text search out of which I had implemented Apache Lucene Search which does work fast than normal Query result but does not solve my Search criteria.

Is there any other Java Library which will help me in this criteria ?

Comment: You need to find terms regardless of singular or plural? See answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085478/configure-solr-to-find-documents-if-the-plural-is-used-in-the-document-and-the) question for example. Edit: This called plural/word *stemming* by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PorterStemmer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/tartarus/snowball/ext/PorterStemmer.html) is a good choice for supporting this sort of stemming in Lucene.  Particularly, incorporating a [PorterStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/PorterStemFilter.html) into your Analyzer would be the typical approach.  There is a simple example of that listed on the `PorterStemFilter` documentation linked, but may look something like (based on the StandardAnalyzer, in this case):

```
class MyStemmerAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    @override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        TokenStream stream = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
        stream = new StandardFilter(stream);
        stream = new LowerCaseFilter(stream);
        stream = new PorterStemFilter(stream);
        stream = new StopFilter(stream, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will give a try & let you know

Comment: how do i apply Stemmer to my search String.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you incorporate the Stemmer into an Analyzer.

Comment: But Now if i search for "gainers" it is giving "gainer" it should have given "gain" (am i right?)

Comment: No, it's not as simple as just stripping off anything that might be a suffix.  You wouldn't want "hammer" reduced to "ham".  The algorithm handles different parts of the word differently, and only removes "-er" after it has seen two sets of a vowel followed by a consonant, so "hammer" is not stemmed, but "hammerer" is.  That is, it only removes "-er" if it falls with the region marked `R2` in [this explanation](http://snowball.tartarus.org/texts/r1r2.html) (see the rest of the algorithm's [explaination here](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html))